# Code formatting a Batch file is breaking the script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

ALl,

I like my indentation and new lines to make my code readable however for some reason it is breaking my batch script.

This works for example:

```
cd %inbox%
for /r %%x in (*.txt) do echo "%%x"
```

However if I try and move the action part of the loop to a new line, the command terminal opens and closes.

```
cd %inbox%
for /r %%x in (*.txt) 
do echo "%%x"
```

I am new to batch scripting so from what I can tell here it seems that it is sensitive to whitespace/ EOL

How can I format this code without breaking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because `for` is a command, and it ends where the line ends. One option would be to add a `^` where you want to split the command, so that the interpreter knows to stitch the current line with the one below before executing the command.

```
cd %inbox%
for /r %%x in (*.txt) ^
do echo "%%x"
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, so EOL is only relevant for commands on that line.

Comment: What about formatting inside the braces of the do , if I want to perform multiple commands inside that?

Comment: A block (with parenthesis) can span multiple lines. You only need to place the opening parenthesis on the same line of the `do`

Answer (score 3):

For formatting you could use code blocks, but it's important that the block begins on the same line like the `do`

```
for /r %%x in (*.txt) do (
  echo %%x
  echo ---
)
```